# How to prevent ffmpeg transcode from low quality to high quality?

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg

I use nginx to build livestream server and use exec command to run ffmpeg for transcode but I don't want transcode with input stream have quality like 640x360 and output stream transcode have quality 1280x720.

This is the command I use to transcode :

```
exec /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1935/$app/$name -c:a aac -b:a 96k -c:v libx264 -vf "scale='if(gte(iw,ih),-2,360)':'if(gte(iw,ih),360,-2)'" -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/360p/$name;
```

The result I want is if input stream have quality 1280x720 or 640x360 then transcode go normal but if input stream have quality 160x120 then don't transcode

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a step to probe the incoming stream to get is properties. Then write a program or script to decide and create the output settings.